# terraform gcp dataflow job is giving me error about name?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, terraform

this is the terraform I am using.

```
  provider "google" {
      credentials = "${file("${var.credentials}")}"
      project     = "${var.gcp_project}"
      region      = "${var.region}"
    }

    resource "google_dataflow_job" "big_data_job" {
      #name = "${var.job_name}"
      template_gcs_path = "gs://dataflow-templates/wordcount/template_file"
      #template_gcs_path = "gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt"
      temp_gcs_location = "gs://bucket-60/counts"
      max_workers       = "${var.max-workers}"
      project           = "${var.gcp_project}"
      zone              = "${var.zone}"
      parameters {
        name = "cloud_dataflow"
      }
    }
```

But I am getting this error.so how can i solve this problem:- 
enter code here Error: Error applying plan:

```
1 error(s) occurred:

* google_dataflow_job.big_data_job: 1 error(s) occurred:

* google_dataflow_job.big_data_job: googleapi: Error 400: (4ea5c17a2a9d21ab): The workflow could not be created. Causes: (4ea5c17a2a9d2052): Found unexpected parameters: ['name' (perhaps you meant 'appName')], badRequest

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.
```

Comment: have you tried changing the parameters.name field to appName?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you've commented out the `name` argument, but [name is required](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/dataflow_job.html#name) for this resource type.

> 1. Remove the leading `#` from this line

```
#name = "${var.job_name}"
```

You've also included `name` as a parameter to the dataflow template, but that example `wordcount` template does not have a `name` parameter, [it only has inputFile and output](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#wordcount):

`inputFile`     The Cloud Storage input file path.
`output`    The Cloud Storage output file path and prefix.

> 2. Remove this part:

```
parameters {
    name = "cloud_dataflow"
}
```